# How to use alias-created commands with wsl command (WSL ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the following line in my `.bashrc` (WSL Ubuntu):

```
alias code="code-insiders"
```

I'm able to run `code .` from an `ubuntu.exe` terminal, but when I run `wsl code .` in `cmd.exe`, I get the following error:

```
/bin/bash: code: command not found
```

Is there a way for me to use `alias`-generated commands with `wsl` from `cmd.exe`?

Thanks!

Comment: No, you'll need to use a function instead of an alias.

Comment: Try the same in `.profile` or `.bash_profile` file. Or run `bash --login`. You will get the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @Biswapriyo's recommendation, I was able to get my `~/.bashrc` to run (And my aliases to show up) by running `bash -ic <cmd>` instead of `wsl <cmd>` e.g.:

```
bash -ic code .
```

However, since `bash.exe` is deprecated, it's probably better to run

```
wsl bash -ic code .
```

Although, that starts to get a bit less convenient.

Comment: for `zsh`, you can use `wsl.exe zsh -ic ${your alias}`.